# Unity 5 Fixed Update

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

In my project written in Unity 5, I am performing the object touch operation with raycast. But, since my object is moving, sometimes raycast cannot reach to my when I touch. As a solution, using fixed update, I set the Fixed Timestep from 0.02 to 0.01 on the project settings. However, at this time, it behaves as if I were touching twice and it receives two touches. I should not use update function and I need to do this using fixed update. How can I solve the problem?

Below is my code:

```
   void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("oyunsonu") == 0) {

        // Code for OnMouseDown in the iPhone. Unquote to test.
        RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit ();
        for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) {
            if (Input.GetTouch (i).phase.Equals (TouchPhase.Began)) {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.GetTouch (i).position);

                touchY = Input.GetTouch (i).position.y;
                if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {

                    //Debug.Log (hit.transform.gameObject.name.ToString ());

                    GameObject myBallObject;
                    myBallObject = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Ball");

                    Instantiate (effect, myBallObject.transform.position, transform.rotation);
                    GetComponent<AudioSource> ().PlayOneShot (saundFile [3], 1);
                    //TextAnimation.Show ();
                    TouchObjectScript myTouchObjectScript = myBallObject.GetComponent<TouchObjectScript> ();
                    myTouchObjectScript.BallForce (hit.transform.gameObject.tag.ToString (), touchY, screenHeight);

                    //PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("aaa", 0);

                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: never change fixed-timestep **for any reason, ever**.  Secondly, it's very unlikely you should be using FixedUpdate.   Finally a minor point you absolutely should not be doing PlayerPrefs.GetInt inside the runloop.

Comment: You don't need to change the fixed timestep, changing it to a smaller value than `0.016` can cause physics problems. Instead, use this code in the Update method, there's nothing stopping you from not using FixedUpdate.

Answer (score 2):

You use `Update()` to detect input or move non physics/rigidbody objects. You use `FixedUpdate()` to move physics object. Watch [UPDATE AND FIXEDUPDATE](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/update-and-fixedupdate) video from Unity.

Doing `GameObject.FindWithTag("Ball");` each time there is touch and raycast is not good. Constantly checking `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("oyunsonu")` is not good either.  Cache your variables if they will be used in a loop multiple times. Below is your fixed code.

```
AudioSource myAudio;
GameObject myBallObject;
TouchObjectScript myTouchObjectScript;
int oyunsonu = 0;

void Start()
{
    myAudio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    myBallObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("Ball");
    myTouchObjectScript = myBallObject.GetComponent<TouchObjectScript>();
    oyunsonu = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("oyunsonu");
}

void Update()
{
    if (oyunsonu == 0)
    {

        // Code for OnMouseDown in the iPhone. Unquote to test.
        RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
        for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(i).position);

                touchY = Input.GetTouch(i).position.y;
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                {
                    //Debug.Log (hit.transform.gameObject.name.ToString ());
                    Instantiate(effect, myBallObject.transform.position, transform.rotation);
                    myAudio.PlayOneShot(saundFile[3], 1);
                    //TextAnimation.Show ();
                    myTouchObjectScript.BallForce(hit.transform.gameObject.tag.ToString(), touchY, screenHeight);
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```